# Proving that a function defined in whole numbers is bijective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:W\to W$ such that $f(x) = x+1$ if $x$ is even and $f(x) = x-1$ if $x$ is odd.
>   Prove the function is bijective.

I realised that the function would look like this:

$\ \ \  \ \ x = 0 \ \ 1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 5 ..$

$f(x) = 1\ \ 0\ \ 3\ \ 2\ \ 5\ \ 4 ..$

But how do we write it in statements?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways.  First is to show surjectivity and injectivity:

- Surjectivity: Suppose $y$ is even. Then $y+1$ is odd, so $f(y+1)=y$. Suppose $y$ is odd.  Then $y-1$ is even, so $f(y-1)=y$.
- Injectivity: Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$.  Then $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are either both even or both odd, and consequently $x$ and $y$ are either both even or both odd. Thus, either $x+1=y+1$ or $x-1=y-1$.  In either case, $x=y$.

Alternatively, you can show that $f$ has an inverse.  In fact, you can check that $f\circ f = \mathrm{id}_\mathbb{N}$.  If $x$ odd, then $f(x)=x-1$ is even, so $f(f(x))=f(x-1)=(x-1)+1$.  Likewise with the case where $x$ is even.

Comment: How is the proof of surjective that you give valid? It doesn't explicitly tell surjectivity! Thank you for response!

Comment: @samjoe The idea to show surjectivity is to pick an arbitrary element in the codomain (in this case it is being called $y$) and show that there is some element in the domain that gets mapped to it. This is exactly what is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that $f$ is injective and surjective. A simple way to show this would be to notice that $f$ is an involution: $f \circ f = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Thank you, but what is involution?